# Perform string comaparison ignoring the diacritics

Tags: sql, sql-server, arabic, collation

I'm trying search in Arabic text in SQL Server and need to ignore the Arabic diacritics.
So I'm using `Arabic_100_CI_AI` collation. but it's not work.

For example for the below query I must get 1, but it has no result!

```
select 1 
 where (N'مُحَمَّد'  Collate Arabic_100_CI_AI) = (N'محمّد' Collate Arabic_100_CI_AI)
```

What is the problem and how can I perform **diacritics insensitive comparison in Arabic text**?

Comment: Really only difference between the to strings in my example is that the first one has Arabic diacritics unlike the second one and I expect that those are equal using diacritic-insensitive collation!

Answer (score 3):

It seems `AI` flag is NOT working for Arabic. You can build your own Unicode Normalization function.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[NormalizeUnicode] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @unicodeWord nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Result nvarchar(max)

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here    
    declare @l int;
    declare @i int;

    SET @l = len(@unicodeWord + '-') - 1
    SET @i = 1;
    SET @Result = '';
    WHILE (@i <= @l)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @c nvarchar(1);
        SET @c = SUBSTRING(@unicodeWord, @i, 1);
        -- 0x064B to 0x65F, 0x0670 are Combining Characters
        -- You may need to perform tests for this character range
        IF NOT (unicode(@c) BETWEEN 0x064B AND 0x065F or unicode(@c) = 0x0670)
            SET @Result = @Result + @c;
        SET @i = @i + 1;
    END

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Result
END
```

Following test should work correctly,

```
select  1
where   dbo.NormalizeUnicode(N'بِسمِ اللہِ الرَّحمٰنِ الرَّحیم') = dbo.NormalizeUnicode(N'بسم اللہ الرحمن الرحیم');
```

**Notes:**

1. You may experience slow performance with this solution
2. The character range I've used in the function is NOT thoroughly tested.
3. For a complete reference on Arabic Unicode Character Set, see this document http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0600.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Your use of collation is correct but if you carefully see the two Arabic words in your query (highlighted bold) they are completely different even though their meaning same and hence you are not getting the result (since comparison is failing)

**N'مُحَمَّد'** and **N'محمّد'**

I am pretty sure, if you try to find out their unicode value using `unicode()` function; their result will be different.

If you try the below query, it will succeed

```
select 1 
 where N'مُحَمَّد'  Collate Arabic_100_CI_AI like '%%'
```

See this post for a better explanation
[Treating certain Arabic characters as identical](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14153/treating-certain-arabic-characters-as-identical)

Comment: your query is succeed for any string! really only difference between the to strings in my example is that the first one has Arabic diacritics unlike the second one and I expect that those are equal using diacritic-insensitive collation!